# php imap headesr message_id to FT_UID or in_reply_to to FT_UID

Tags: php, imap, procmail

Is there any way that I can find message FT_UID if I have raw **message_id**

- `(bfd14a45-88ef-4404-b7fd-dbbf8ec8241b@domain.com)`? 
  Or **in_reply_to** raw id 
  `(20120717101453.4074313004BD@zumance.pregmatch.org) to FT_UID?`

Or is there any way that I can pipe somehow messages trough **procmail** and track this things.

Comment: The answer is yes.  What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: anyone can help me with this?

Comment: I tried imap_search but in where (TEXT, SUBJECT ...). Anyway I tried All but no succes. Of course I can grep /var/vmail/user/cur and find message that I am looking for but that is not what I need.

Comment: Only solution that I can think of is to: grep -H 20121116004258.82DA419FE001 \ /var/vmail/username@doamin/cur/* -R > somefile And then to parse raw mail, but that is kind of stupid. What do you think guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try imap_uid function that return the UID number of message

```
int imap_uid ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number )
```

Here, $imap_stream is return by imap_open

for about more, follow this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-uid.php